# Footer menu for mobile

Tags: html, css

How could I better put a row of icons in this phone footer to have as shortcuts?

Look how I did it but it didn't work out

```css
.footer_mobile {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #4af07c;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase; 
}

.footer_mobil a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center; 
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/5430ef00bc.js"></script>

<div class="footer_mobile">
    <a target="_blank" href="">
      <i class="fa fa-google" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-google" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <a target="_blank" href="">
      <i class="fa fa-google" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-google" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

And it shows me something like that
[image]

And I would like 4 icons in a row and I can assign them a link

What is the best method?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it with pseudo elements and flexbox.

**[JSFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/abqzuptr/)**

```css
.footer-mobile {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #4af07c;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase; 
}

.footer-mobile__links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.footer-mobile__link a {
  padding: 0 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.footer-mobile__link a::before {
    content: "\f1a0";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/5430ef00bc.js"></script>
<div class="footer-mobile">
  <div class="footer-mobile__links">
      <div class="footer-mobile__link">
        <a href="#"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-mobile__link">
        <a href="#"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-mobile__link">
        <a href="#"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-mobile__link">
           <a href="#"></a>     
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Different icons

You can find the unicodes for the icons [here](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/)

```css
.footer-mobile {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #4af07c;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase; 
}

.footer-mobile__links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.footer-mobile__link a {
  padding: 0 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-mobile__link a::before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}

.footer-mobile__link--google a::before {
    content: "\f1a0";
    color: black;
}

.footer-mobile__link--youtube a::before {
    content: "\f167";
    color: red;
}

.footer-mobile__link--linked-in a::before {
    content: "\f08c";
    color: blue;
}

.footer-mobile__link--stack-overflow a::before {
    content: "\f16c";
    color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/5430ef00bc.js"></script>

<div class="footer-mobile">
  <div class="footer-mobile__links">
      <div class="footer-mobile__link footer-mobile__link--google">
        <a href="#"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-mobile__link footer-mobile__link--youtube">
        <a href="#"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-mobile__link footer-mobile__link--linked-in">
        <a href="#"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-mobile__link footer-mobile__link--stack-overflow">
           <a href="#"></a>     
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Resize the window to see the changes.
**Note**: This is a simple code, you can improve it by adding `divs` and `classes` to the `li` and the `icons` to design it better. Just the concept.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#nav > ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

#nav > ul > li {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

#nav > ul > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #121212;
}

#nav > ul > li > a > ion-icon {
  display: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  background: #1a7523;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
  #nav {
    bottom: 0;
    top: unset;
    background: #20992c;
    height: 50px;
  }
  
  #nav > ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  #nav > ul > li {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  #nav > ul > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #121212;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  #nav > ul > li > a > ion-icon {
    display: block;
  }
  
  #nav > ul > li > a > span {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
               <span>Home</span>
               <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span>Gallery</span>
                <ion-icon name="image"></ion-icon>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span>Settings</span>
                <ion-icon name="build"></ion-icon>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span>Messages</span>
                <ion-icon name="chatbox"></ion-icon>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.2.3/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use display : flex.
.footer_mobile {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #4af07c;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```